# Kazakhstan hydro datasets

Tags: data-request, geospatial, asia, hydrology

I am looking for river and lake data-sets for Kazakhstan region. I have already got data from [osm_geofabriks](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html). Are there any other sites which will offer me data-sets?? The format of the data-set can be .shp or .csv.

Comment: I have edited my question. by hydro I meant lake,river,reservoir, streams etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Natural Earth Data](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/) has [Rivers and Lake Centerlines](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/110m-rivers-lake-centerlines/) and [Lakes and Reservoirs](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/110mlakes-reservoirs/).

The [USGS Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) will let you download data from anywhere in the world. Type "Kazakhstan" into the place search criteria box, click over to data sets and type "hydro" into the data set search box. The dataset called [GTOPO30 HYDRO1K](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-digital-elevation-hydro1k?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects) is a hydrology raster. There's a download that covers all of Asia (Entity ID: GT30H1KAS). There's also a data set called "SRTM Water body data."

Update: Roshualine found that GTOPO30 HYDRO1K shapefile just had a polygon with no attributes. They ended up using a subset of the Kazakhstan region from Natural Earth.

Comment: GTOPO30 HYDRO1K shapefile just had a polygon with no attributes. But Natural Earth was helpful, I subsetted the Kazakhstan region.